# Selenium Ide - error element id not found

Tags: selenium, testing, ide, automated-tests

I have two websites that I have to make sure that are completely the same. 
So far I am only familiar to Selenium Ide. 
I got stuck on a radio button click command - I am getting: 
[error] Element id=blabla not found
I've checked with the inspector both websites, the id-s are the same. What could be the reason for this?

Since I am newbie to selenium I would really appreciate a detailed step-by-step description. 
Thanks!

Comment: I've found that in some cases clickAndWait command helps, but still there are radio buttons, dropdown toggles and some other element, that I am getting "element not found error every time" Could it be that I have to use another command for them?

Comment: Please post your application code as well as HTML. Thanks.